# How to find out if a user logged in every day in the last 10 days?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I am using mysql and have a table (Log_Table) storing user login dates, a kind of logging table. I need to find out for how many days in a row a user is logged in or 
I need to find out if the user is logged-in everyday in the past 10 days. The thing is that I need to find it in only one SQL select command.
The Log_Table has one `user_id:int` and one `login_date:DATE` field

Comment: How do you define day? For example, For example you could use midnight to midnight in UTC, but this could cause a lot of confusion for users in other time zones where midnight UTC might be in the middle of the day.

Comment: I am using mysql server time CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default data, so it is not a big deal.

Comment: @MarkByers, is that a comment on SE :-).

Comment: "it is not a big deal." It *could* be a big deal for some of your users if you reward them for logins on consecutive days but they can't understand what your definition of a day means (not everyone understands UTC). Some users might lose their streak without being able to understand why.

Comment: Ok then, from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 is a day (inclusive). say if a user is logged in on 16/06/2012 20:00:00 and then the next day 17/06/2012 08:00:00 then it is considered as 2 days in a row. (All in mysql server time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56437/7

```
SELECT user_id,
       COUNT( DISTINCT DATE( login_date )) AS days
FROM   Log_Table
WHERE  login_date > DATE_SUB( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 3 DAY )
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING days >= 3;
```